# Remove "Optional[...]" from a Console OutPrint in Java / IntelliJ

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm studying programming and I'm working on streams in Java. I wrote a methode which should return the tallest Human-Object out of a doctors-patient List.

```
public static void tallestPatient(List<Human> patients) throws NullPointerException {
    try {
        System.out.println("Tallest patient: ");
        System.out.print(patients.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Human::getHeight)));
        System.out.println();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The method itself works. I just noticed, that there's this "Optional[...]" Tag ont the console whenever I try to print the toString() Method of the choosen Object (tallest Human) out.

Console-Output:

Tallest patient:
Optional[Peter is a man with private insurance from USA and is about 220cm high.]

IDE told me, that's because the element could be zero if it's a empty list. tried to cancel that out, by considering NullPointerExceptions as well as an if and else condition, which also didn't solve the problem, why is stayed with the exception variant.

Does anyone have an idea, what I could fix?

Greetings Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregate function [`Stream::max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), and the `toString`-implementation of `Optional` produces the `String` we observe.

We can prevent this by unwrapping the `Optional`. One possible way would be to call [`Optional::orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)):

```
System.out.print(patients.stream()
  .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Human::getHeight))
  .orElse(null));
```

Another possibility would be to only `print` the value if a value is present through [`Optional::ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)):

```
patients.stream()
  .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Human::getHeight))
  .ifPresent(System.out::println)
```

---

A remark on the code: The decision to catch the `NullPointerException` is at least questionable. I would advice to enforce non-`null`ity explicitly.